# Save NSString after pushing through more than 4 views?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I'm creating an application that asks basic "YES" or "NO" questions and I have about 7 different views that I am displaying for each question.

In my .h file:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *click1A;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *click1B;
```

In my .m file:

```
FinalReadingViewController *final = [[FinalReadingViewController alloc] init];
final.oneB = self.click1B = @"1B";
```

I've declared a variable in my FinalReadingController as oneB. So Basically what I'm asking is how do I save all of these strings in the Final View Controller after the entire line of questioning has been completed?

Comment: What have you tried to do to save the data? Where do you want it to be saved to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using NSUserDefaults?

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:aString forKey:aKey]
```

Comment: Okay, awesome! Now my next question would be, every time after I run the application is that string stored forever, and every time after that will it call the same string with that key or will it reset? Thank you, btw.

Comment: It's stored after closing the app, and it doesn't reset when retrieving it.

Comment: Is there anyway to reset it after closing the app or push to another view?